# Express.js: Simple Get request takes a while to load?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I was playing around with Express and Typescript when I noticed that the load time for a simple GET request was ~700ms. For a normal webapp, this isn't really a big deal but considering the response I'm sending for my GET request is just 'Hello get', I thought it was a little weird.

When I tested this with just plain JS, I got the same load time.

Any idea on what's causing this?

Here's the code in case that helps

```js
// index.ts

import app from "./app";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)});
```

```js
// app/index.ts

import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import api from "./routes/api";

class App 
{
    public app: express.Application;

    constructor()
    {
        this.app = express();
        this.config();
        this.routes();
    }

    private config() 
    {
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
        this.app.use(morgan("dev"));
    }

    private routes() 
    {
        this.app.use("/api", api);
    }
}

export default new App().app;
```

```js
// routes/api.ts

import { Request, Response, Router } from "express";

class Api
{
    public api: Router = Router();

    constructor()
    {
        this.api.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
            res.send("Hello get");
        });
    }
}

export default new Api().api;
```

Comment: Try removing morgan

Comment: Only went down by like ~20ms, I tried removing the router entirely and seeing if adding the route directly to the express app variable would change anything but nothing there either.

Comment: is there any middleware that is adding a simulated delay?

Comment: There shouldn't be. All my middlewares are in config(). When I ran express in debug however, it says the response time was only 2.289ms. Now I'm completely lost.

Comment: This might actually just be a browser issue. Using the 'got' package, the time it gave me was something much faster than what chrome was telling me.